# how to get the correct caret position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a contenteditable based input and I want to add emoticon support

i have the contenteditable div, and inside is only text and IMG_TAG for emoticons. On blur, I want to save the caret position. And when I click to open the emoticon box to focus the contenteditable and set the caret where it was.  Something to simulate web.whatsapp.com behaviour

I've found this piece of code

```
function getCaretCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
    var caretOffset = 0;
    var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    var sel;
    if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
            preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
        }
    } else if ((sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        var textRange = sel.createRange();
        var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
        caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
    }
    return caretOffset;
}
```

But it does not give me the correct position.

"hello IMG_TAG john". If the cursor is just before the IMG_TAG -> the position is 6, which is correct, but if it is just after the IMG_TAG is still 6.
Also, I didn't find a good "setCaretPosition" function to work well for me.

I've been searching for two hours now. Anyone got a good answer ?

Answer (score 0):

In the demo we have used the Selection and Range APIs for for setting and **getting** the caret's position. Since the OP needs to find a caret's position, we will concentrate on the `getCaret()` function:

```
    var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

    btn2.addEventListener('click', getCaret, false);

    function getCaret() {
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      var end = sel.focusOffset;
      var out1 = document.getElementById('out1');
      out1.textContent = end;
    }
```

- The function references the Selection object
- Then you store the Selection object's property, [`focusOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/focusOffset)
- `focusOffset` will give us an integer representing the number of characters there are between it (focusNode) and the beginning of the Selection (anchorNode). If the Selection contains an element, then it includes the element's childNodes into the count as well.

When testing the `getCaret()` function, just select some text, then click the <kbd>Get Focus</kbd> button, the result is displayed next to the area labeled `Caret Position:`

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <style>
    fieldset {
      margin: 20px auto;
    }
    input {
      width: 5ex;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1px 3px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="editor1" contenteditable="true">
    <br/>123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    <br/>12 45678 abcd fg ijk mnopqrst vwxyz
    <br/>123 5 789a cde ghijklm o qrst v xyz
    <br/>12345 789abcd fg ijklmnopq s u wxyz
    <br/>123 567 9abc efg ijklm op rst vwxy
    <br/>1 34 6789a cdef hij lm opq stuvwxyz
    <br/>1 3456 89a cd fghij l no qrst vwx z
    <br/>12 4 6789 bcd fgh j lmno q stuv xy
  </div>
  <fieldset>

    <input type="button" class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand('italic',false,null);" value="I" title="Italicize Highlighted Text">
    <input type="button" class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand('bold',false,null);" value="B" title="Bold Highlighted Text">
    <input id="row" name="row" placeholder="Row#" />
    <input id="col" name="col" placeholder="Col#" />
    <button id="btn1">Set Focus</button>
    <button id="btn2">Get Focus</button>
    <label for='out1'>Caret Position:</label>
    <output id="out1"></output>
  </fieldset>
  <p>Each row has a number of non-repeated string of alphanumeric characters:</p>
  <pre><code>123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</code></pre>
  <p>Maximum of 35 characters. Every row except the first row has some missing characters and in their place is a whitespace.
  </p>
  <script>
    function setCaret(x, y) {

      var ele = document.getElementById("editor1");
      var rng = document.createRange();
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      var row = parseInt(x, 10) * 2;
      var col = parseInt(y, 10);
      rng.setStart(ele.childNodes[row], col);
      rng.collapse(true);
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(rng);
      ele.focus();
    }

    function getCaret() {
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      var end = sel.focusOffset;
      var out1 = document.getElementById('out1');
      out1.textContent = end;
    }


    var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
    var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');

    btn1.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var rowSet = document.getElementById('row').value;
      var colSet = document.getElementById('col').value;
      setCaret(rowSet, colSet);
    }, true);

    btn2.addEventListener('click', getCaret, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Just figured it out after trying to remember how `setCaret()` function worked.

Comment: Have you tried `removeAllRanges` and `collapse(true)` before you make a new attempt to get the caret position?

Comment: don't know how.. all those range functions are new to me

Comment: @John got it, check it out.